# Figuring out nilpotent $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

So far I know that in the $2 \times 2$ case, the matrices $A =$

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & a \\
  0 & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 \\
  a & 0  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

and

\begin{pmatrix}
  a & a \\
  -a & -a  \\
 \end{pmatrix}

Satisfy $A^2 = 0$, but I'm not sure if this is all of them.  I don't think there should be any others.

Also, are there $2 \times 2$ matrices which satisfy $A^3 = 0$ or $A^4 = 0$ or $A^5=0$, etc... but not $A^2 = 0$?  I want to say "no" but I'm having a hard time explaining why.

Comment: Check out the index of nilpotency: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NilpotentMatrix.html, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200829/all-nilpotent-2-times-2-matrices.

Answer (score 1):

The trace and the determinant must be zero. So force the trace to be zero
by taking
$$A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&-a}.$$
The square of this is zero iff $-a^2+bc=0$ so we can take $c=-a^2/b$
if $a\ne0$. (You've already done the $a=0$ case.)

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to consider matrices such that $A^2=0$.

Indeed, if $A^m v=0$ but $A^{m-1}\ne 0$, then $v, Av, A^2v,\dots , A^{m-1}v$ are linearly independent (see an easy proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2242327/prove-that-v-tv-t2v-tm-1v-is-linearly-independent)).
Therefore, if $A$ a nilpotent $2 \times 2$ matrix, then $A^2=0$.